# Suggestions for LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq, average

I have the following class for storing data in a List:

```
public class Values
    {
        public int ParamId { get; set; }
        public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }
        public double Value { get; set; }
    }
```

And I am doing the following:

```
IList<Values> val = new List<Values>();
//12 december 2011 10 hour
Values v1 = new Values { ParamId = 100, TimeStamp = new DateTime(2011, 12, 20, 10, 0, 0), Value = 345.0d };
Values v2 = new Values { ParamId = 100, TimeStamp = new DateTime(2011, 12, 20, 10, 0, 1), Value = 350.0d };
Values v3 = new Values { ParamId = 100, TimeStamp = new DateTime(2011, 12, 20, 10, 0, 2), Value = 355.0d };
Values v4 = new Values { ParamId = 100, TimeStamp = new DateTime(2011, 12, 20, 10, 0, 3), Value = 344.0d };

Values g1 = new Values { ParamId = 101, TimeStamp = new DateTime(2011, 12, 20, 10, 0, 0), Value = 3000.0d };
Values g2 = new Values { ParamId = 101, TimeStamp = new DateTime(2011, 12, 20, 10, 0, 1), Value = 3100.0d };
Values g3 = new Values { ParamId = 101, TimeStamp = new DateTime(2011, 12, 20, 10, 0, 2), Value = 3150.0d };
Values g4 = new Values { ParamId = 101, TimeStamp = new DateTime(2011, 12, 20, 10, 0, 3), Value = 3125.0d };

Values v5 = new Values { ParamId = 100, TimeStamp = new DateTime(2011, 12, 20, 10, 3, 0), Value = 355.0d };
Values v6 = new Values { ParamId = 100, TimeStamp = new DateTime(2011, 12, 20, 10, 3, 1), Value = 360.0d };
Values v7 = new Values { ParamId = 100, TimeStamp = new DateTime(2011, 12, 20, 10, 3, 2), Value = 365.0d };
Values v8 = new Values { ParamId = 100, TimeStamp = new DateTime(2011, 12, 20, 10, 3, 3), Value = 360.0d };

Values g5 = new Values { ParamId = 101, TimeStamp = new DateTime(2011, 12, 20, 10, 3, 0), Value = 3150.0d };
Values g6 = new Values { ParamId = 101, TimeStamp = new DateTime(2011, 12, 20, 10, 3, 1), Value = 3200.0d };
Values g7 = new Values { ParamId = 101, TimeStamp = new DateTime(2011, 12, 20, 10, 3, 2), Value = 3250.0d };
Values g8 = new Values { ParamId = 101, TimeStamp = new DateTime(2011, 12, 20, 10, 3, 3), Value = 3225.0d };
//............... up to 57 minutes

Values v9 = new Values { ParamId = 100, TimeStamp = new DateTime(2011, 12, 20, 10, 57, 0), Value = 350.0d };
Values v10 = new Values { ParamId = 100, TimeStamp = new DateTime(2011, 12, 20, 10, 57, 1), Value = 365.0d };
Values v11 = new Values { ParamId = 100, TimeStamp = new DateTime(2011, 12, 20, 10, 57, 2), Value = 367.0d };
Values v12 = new Values { ParamId = 100, TimeStamp = new DateTime(2011, 12, 20, 10, 57, 3), Value = 370.0d };

Values g9 = new Values { ParamId = 101, TimeStamp = new DateTime(2011, 12, 20, 10, 57, 0), Value = 3250.0d };
Values g10 = new Values { ParamId = 101, TimeStamp = new DateTime(2011, 12, 20, 10, 57, 1), Value = 3240.0d };
Values g11 = new Values { ParamId = 101, TimeStamp = new DateTime(2011, 12, 20, 10, 57, 2), Value = 3200.0d };
Values g12 = new Values { ParamId = 101, TimeStamp = new DateTime(2011, 12, 20, 10, 57, 3), Value = 3235.0d };

val.Add(v1); val.Add(v2); val.Add(v3); val.Add(v4);
val.Add(v5); val.Add(v6); val.Add(v7); val.Add(v8);
val.Add(v9); val.Add(v10); val.Add(v11); val.Add(v12);

val.Add(g1); val.Add(g2); val.Add(g3); val.Add(g4);
val.Add(g5); val.Add(g6); val.Add(g7); val.Add(g8);
val.Add(g9); val.Add(g10); val.Add(g11); val.Add(g12);
```

I want to get hourly data from this three-minute data by calculating average for each parameter. For example, data with time 00:00, 00:03, 00:06, ... , 00:57, to calculate the average value for parameters 100 and 101 for 00 hours. In reality, the range of data in val List maybe few hour or few days.

How to can I do this correctly and with good code? Thanks.

Comment: Please can you write the last part a bit more clearly? It's really difficult to tell what you're actually trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
var valuesByHourQuery = from val in vals
                        group val by val.ParamId into valsByParam
                        select new
                        {
                            ParamId = valsByParam.Key,
                            AvarageValues = from v in valsByParam
                                            let timeStampWithoutMinutes = new DateTime(v.TimeStamp.Year, v.TimeStamp.Month, v.TimeStamp.Day, v.TimeStamp.Hour, 0, 0)
                                            group v by timeStampWithoutMinutes into valsByHours 
                                            select new
                                            {
                                                Hour = valsByHours.Key,
                                                Value = valsByHours.Average(v => v.Value)
                                            }
                        };
```

Comment: For your LINQ code average in 10 hour will be 357.166666666667, but right value is 358. Where is mistake? 10 hourly value must include range 00:00:00.000 and to 23:59:59.000. Thanks.